# Show the list of players on the Player Count Hover

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bungeecord

I have a simple Bungeecord Server. It has one server in it, and this server holds, at a maximum, 32 players. I would like it to show the list of players exactly where it is on a regular CraftBukkit Server

By player list I mean this:
[image: Player Count Hover]

I have been unable to find any plugins that do this, nor any settings in the Bungeecord config.yml .

Answer (score 1):

This plugin seems to be what you are looking for

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/serverlistplus.241/

There is an image on the website but it failed to load.

this website has these features

ServerListPlus provides options in the configuration for:

- Description/Motd
- Favicons (Server icons): Load from files, URLs, oruse the player's head for example
- Maximum player count
- Custom player slot format
- Player Hover Message: Displayed when a player hovers the player count in the server list
- Virtual/Forced Hosts: Use a custom configuration if players ping the server by using a special IP/hostname to connect with
- Multiple entries to choose a random one from the list
- Personalize the status ping by adding the player's name to the messages

The features page in the wiki describes all features in detail.

Comment: The interesting one would be [Player Hover Messages](https://github.com/Minecrell/ServerListPlus/wiki/Status-Configuration#player-hover-messages), but I don't think it quite does what OP is trying to achieve. It may be possible to make it do that though.

Comment: Please don't just copy paste from other sources - rephrase it if possible.

Comment: I just copy pasted because I think that would be enough for the asker to understand and discern if this was his plugin or not. However if he finds it unclear I will update the post

Comment: It might be possible using [random player list](https://github.com/Minecrell/ServerListPlus/wiki/Placeholders#random-player-list). Something like this could work: `%random_players,%online%|\n%`

Comment: I'm looking for something that would display it **exactly** like a spigot server would. My server is bungee, but regular players only have access to one server on it, and I would like them to think that they are on a regular spigot server. I have already looked at and gone through the features of ServerListPlus, and was unable to find something that would do this in it.